# Facebook: Permission "user_activities" is missing in v2.6

Tags: facebook, user-interface

It is found that the permission "**user_activities**" is not available in the Facebook Graph API **v2.6**. Tried to find out the actual impact of it while querying the user profile using the Facebook Graph API.

We are basically interested in the following fields of the user:

about,address,bio,age_range,cover,birthday,currency,education,email,link,last_name,location,locale,id,name,middle_name,name_format,first_name,gender,timezone,work,devices,favorite_athletes,favorite_teams,hometown,inspirational_people,languages,meeting_for,political,quotes,relationship_status,religion,security_settings,third_party_id,updated_time,verified,significant_other,website,interested_in,picture

What does the permission "user_activities" impact on the data of user we retrieved from the facebook using the Facebook Graph API.

[image]

Comment: What do you do with all those fields?

Comment: We want to extract values for those fields.

Comment: That is pretty obvious. Just curious because I would never use an app that asked for almost every permission that exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edges and Permissions - /v2.3/{user_id}/interests and /v2.3/{user_id}/activities edges as well as user_interests and user_activities permissions are deprecated in v2.3.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3

Activity Examples: Running, Climbing, ... Just select the API Explorer App in the API Explorer and v2.2 to test it: `/me/activities`.

Btw, this may be interesting for you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Comment: Thanks. 
How do we add activity such asa Running, Climbing in Facebook?

Comment: I mean from the Facebook using browser not from the api. I just wanted to play with activity like you mentioned.

Comment: i can´t find it, maybe they removed it completely